# Get id value of nearest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div table and would like to get the id value of the class `live-mu-table-tdq` that is to the left of where I click. I thought that the following code would work but it didn't.

```
 $(this).closest(".live-mu-table-tdq").attr("id");
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/141swjzj/2/)

```
<div class="live-mu-table" >
    <div class="live-mu-tablee-tr">
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdq" id="q-1">q1 goes here</div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdspacer1"></div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tda" id="a-3"> 3 the answer</div>
    </div>

    <div class="live-mu-tablee-tr">
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdq" id="q-2">q2 question</div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdspacer1"></div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tda" id="a-1">answer 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="live-mu-tablee-tr">
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdq" id="q-3">question 3</div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tdspacer1"></div>
        <div class="live-mu-table-tda" id="a-2">the answer 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".live-mu-table-tda").click(function() { 
    var abc = $(this).closest(".live-mu-table-tdq").attr("id");
    alert (abc)   
});
```

Comment: `.closest` searches _up_ in the DOM, looking for ancestors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.live-mu-table-tdq` element is a sibling of the `live-mu-table-tda` element so you need to use `siblings()`, not `closest()`:

```
$(".live-mu-table-tda").click(function() {
    var abc = $(this).siblings(".live-mu-table-tdq").prop("id");
    alert(abc)
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/141swjzj/4/)

Answer (score 2):

`.closest()` look upwards in the DOM. I believe `.siblings(".live-mu-table-tdq").attr("id")` is what you are after

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

you could try .next or .find

```
$(this).next(".live-mu-table-tdq").attr("id");
$(this).find(".live-mu-table-tdq").attr("id");
```